# React native image resizeMode set to "contain" , on Android the image not showing

Tags: android, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

After trying for couple of days with lots of trial and error I had found that the issue is caused when I use < Image > component with props `resizeMode="contain"`. If I use `resizeMode="cover"` , the issue is not there. However, I need that props in order to place the image properly and it seems the only option.
By the way, `resizeMode="contain"` works perfectly on IOS.

Comment: I might have seen this problem before. Did you provide image width and height in source prop? You can also try specifying component size using width and height props or in style.

Comment: Yes. I set image width and height in style prop. But the image did not show up.

Comment: Yes this occurs for me, too, any idea how to solve it? BTW I'm embedding the image in another image, not sure if that is connected.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who still faced this bug (mine is `react-native 0.63.4`), please use the `react-native-fast-image`. you will can still keep all options inside and just change `<Image` to `<FastImage`